# Nginx setting expires header with proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have the following base Nginx configuration (pre-installed Ghost platform on DigitalOcean droplet):

```
server {
    listen 80;                                                             
    server_name xxx.com;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to set the following expiry header for my assets but without success:

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Based on the information I've found, Nginx only uses one location path at a time so have to copy the proxy_* parameters inside the assets location block. If I just copy them I get an error (regex with proxy_pass) that can be solved by rewriting the URL before passing it to the proxy. I already did some experiments with that but I don't get it to work either.

Does anyone have an example of how to set expiry headers when a proxy_pass is present? I simply want all files under xxx.com/assets/ to have the proper expiry date.

Comment: Why do you use regex location? Just write `location /assets/ {`...

Comment: Using /assets/ results in 404's when querying xxx.com/assets/css/style.css for example. (Note that I also copied the proxy settings inside this location block.) I did notice that querying /assets/ will result in an HTTP GET with the proper expiry date.

EDIT: Based on the Nginx logs, all requests to /assets/css/style.css are rewritten to /css/styles.css. Hence the 404.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
location /assets/ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";

    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/assets/;
    # or proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Nginx doc for [proxy_pass](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) say that:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

I your case `/assets/` get replaced by `/` (which is an URI). To avoid that either use `proxy_pass` with URI equal to location prefix (`proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/assets/;`) or don't use URI at all (`proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;`). But in latter case nginx will proxy unnormalized URI.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the answer. This way I know my own solution (posted below) was correct :).

Answer (score 4):

Managed to solve it by using the script below (note the /assets/ after the proxy).

```
server {
    listen 80;                                                             
    server_name xaviertalpe.be;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location /assets/ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";

        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/assets/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```